# Is there any way to recreate the CSS dog-ear effect on Twitter?

Tags: html, css, twitter

When you retweet or favourite on Twitter, a little coloured triangle with an icon appears in the corner of the div containing the tweet. I've copied the CSS and sprite sheet from Twitter and tried to recreate it on my site, but it didn't quite go to plan (the triangle didn't appear at all using the exact same CSS). So, how would I add a triangle 'dog-ear' effect to the corners of divs on my site?

This was the code I copied from Twitter:

```
.dogear {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  display:none;
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
}

.retweeted .dogear {
  background-position:0 -450px;
}

.favorited .dogear {
  background-position:-30px -450px;
}

.retweeted.favorited .dogear {
  background-position:-60px -450px;
}

.retweeted .dogear,.favorited .dogear,.retweeted.favorited .dogear{
  display:block;
}

i {
  background-image: url("../sprite.png") !important;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url("../sprite.png");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And inserted into the HTML using:

```
<i class="dogear"></i>
```

I changed the sprite sheet URI and I was going to change the class names, and add some in so it wasn't exactly the same. Is it possible to make this effect work?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a larger `z-index` property to the element containing the dog-ear so that it appears on top of the element you wish it to appear to overlap.

`z-index` is used to control the stack order of elements that are positioned absolutely, relatively or fixed.

You can read more on `z-index` [on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

In addition, you're using the `dogear` class in isolation from what I can tell from the code you've pasted. Which, if you look at the class definition in the stylesheet, is told to not display: `display: none;`